# OBIEE 12c RPD how to put sql code in session variable as default

Tags: obiee

I have a session variable in the RPD of OBIEE 12c and I wanted to put a small sql code in it as default initializer. It's something that selects only one row but this gives a syntax error (the sql is correct, I've tested it). Is this possible? Or are there any other ways to make the default dynamic?

There is also one other thing: I only have the category constants in my tab 'category' of the expression builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use SQL to set your default initializer, that's why you only see Constants as an option. It's meant to be a constant value. The initialization block is used to set your session variable to a dynamic value.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/variables.htm#BIEMG3104

Answer (score 0):

You want the content of the variable to be a SQL statement as a string?

Like VALUEOF(NQ_SESSION.MYVAR) = 'select ''This is jist some text'' from dual;"?

Cause that's what you then get. Text. Uninterpreted. Like typing a sentence, not code.

Comment: Not really, what you are saying is a line implemented in OBIEE, but I need a sql code in the RPD when initialising the default. So I actually want the default to be variable, and selecting from an existing table in our database.

Comment: No. What I am saying works everywhere within OBI and I have problems understanding what you want.

a) The RPD is part of OBI. I guess you meant "in the front-end" or "in Answers".

b) If your default initializer yields errors then you have to investigate what that error is precisely and where it comes from.

As I said it would be good if you could explain what you're trying to achieve and your problem more in detail since like this it's hard to help you.